# Why doesn't mailto has // after the scheme

Tags: uri, mailto

While writing a library code to generate URI strings, I got confused about mailto. According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2) authority for a URI must be preceded by `//`. Authority is the part of URI where the userinfo and host resides in userinfo@host syntax. According to this RFC the format should be: `mailto://me@host.com`. However, it is used as `mailto:me@host.com` not just in the wild but also shown like that in [RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) and [RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068).

The only way mailto being a URI is that the email is appended as path, which doesn't make much sense. Is this assumption correct or is there another point I am missing.

Comment: Oh, I searched it for a while, but never thought someone would use URL instead of URI. It indeed answers my question. I think I would edit that answer and the question a little so that it would be found when someone searches like I did.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that mailto is a URN, even if it feels a bit strange. Thus in `mailto:me@host.com`, `me@host.com` is indeed path for URI as described in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3)

Comment: Nope. mailto is a URL according to the old rfc2368. And according to rfc3986 `me@host.com` is a path. The `//` is omitted because there is no authority in mailto URLs.

Comment: Also URNs must start with "urn:" according to rfc2141 and rfc8141.